# 403 Forbidden getting returned by Auth0 in .net core MVC app

Tags: c#, .net-core, auth0

## Problem Statement

A locally deployed dotnet core MVC app is returning a 403 Forbidden when I send a GET request to the health endpoint indicating the user is authenticated but not authorized to use that resource.

### Questions

1. Do I need to setup a User and Roles in Auth0 for this to work?
2. Is there additional code needed for dotnet core Policy-Based Authorization than the code I've provided below?
3. Since the ScopeHandler handles a Requirement asynchronously does my controller action need to be async?

## Resources used so far

[Auth0 tutorial for dotnet core Authorization](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/aspnet-core-webapi/01-authorization)

[Working with Auth0 locally](https://auth0.com/docs/dev-lifecycle/local-testing-and-development#use-local-domains-with-auth0)

## Relevant code

### Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    string domain = $"https://{Configuration["Auth0:domain"]}/";
    services.AddAuthentication(opts => {
        opts.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        opts.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddJwtBearer(opts => {
        opts.Authority = domain;
        opts.Audience = Configuration["Auth0:Identifier"];
        opts.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    });

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("check:health", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new HasScopeRequirement("check:health", domain)));
    });

    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, ScopeHandler>();

    services.AddDbContext<PathosContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlite(Configuration["PathosConnectionString"])
    );
}
```

### HasScopeRequirement.cs

```
public class HasScopeRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public string Issuer { get; }
    public string Scope { get; }

    public HasScopeRequirement(string scope, string issuer)
    {
        Scope = scope ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(scope));
        Issuer = issuer ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(issuer));
    }
}
```

### ScopeHandler.cs

```
public class ScopeHandler : AuthorizationHandler<HasScopeRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, HasScopeRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (!context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "scope" && c.Issuer == requirement.Issuer))
            return Task.CompletedTask;

        var scopes = context.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "scope" && c.Issuer == requirement.Issuer).Value.Split(' ');

        if (scopes.Any(s => s == requirement.Scope))
            context.Succeed(requirement);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

### HealthController.cs

```
public class HealthController: Controller
{
    [Authorize("check:health")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index() {
        return Ok("healthy");
    }
}
```

## Steps

1. Remove the scope/permission from the `[Authorize]` annotation. RESULT: 200 OK returned as expected
2. Move `context.Succeed(requirement);` and `return Task.CompletedTask` to the top of `HandleRequirementAsync` method. RESULT 200 OK response returned as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out all the code was right but there was a misconfiguration in the Auth0 tenant. Under Dashboard > APIs > Machine to Machine Applications > Your Client App > Scopes is where scopes get applied to a specific client.